# loop through list of employee IDs for INDEX & MATCH template?

Tags: vba

I have a workbook with Employee ID's in (Control Sheet), Data with their ID's and various comp info (Data Sheet) and a sheet displaying a template with their compensation statements (Merit Sheet).

The Merit sheet has a form template that populates a bunch of boxes based on Index/Match formulas (all referencing from the employee ID in cell P1 on that sheet).

My coworker is using this incredibly complex VBA script that is prone to errors, and I was wondering if there's a simpler way to do this:

1. go to control sheet, find first employee ID (there is a header row)
2. populate that ID in cell P1 of Merit sheet
3. take that newly filled in data and export as a .pdf
4. loop to the next employee ID in the control sheet until all have been made into .pdfs in the merit sheet.

original code:

```
Sub Statement_Autoprint()
'
' Macro1 Macro

Dim StartTime As Date
StartTime = Now()

Dim MCST As Workbook
Set MCST = ActiveWorkbook
Dim User As String
User = Environ$("Username")
Dim SavePath As String
Dim MgrPath As String
SavePath = "C:\Users\" & User & "\Desktop\Manual Comp Statements\"

If Dir(SavePath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
    MkDir SavePath
End If

Dim LoopRow As Integer
Dim Printed As Integer
LoopRow = 2
Printed = 0

Dim Emplid As String
Dim EmpName As String
Dim MgrName As String
Dim Statement As String
Dim Range As Range
Dim rowstocheck As Range
'With MCST.Sheets(Statement)

'End With

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Do While Trim(MCST.Sheets("Control Sheet").Range("B" & LoopRow)) <> ""

    If Trim(MCST.Sheets("Control Sheet").Range("A" & LoopRow)) <> "" Then
        Statement = MCST.Sheets("Control Sheet").Range("A" & LoopRow)
        Emplid = Format(MCST.Sheets("Control Sheet").Range("B" & LoopRow), "000000000")

        MCST.Sheets(Statement).Activate
        MCST.Sheets(Statement).Calculate
        MCST.Sheets(Statement).Range("P1") = Emplid
            Set rowstocheck = MCST.Sheets(Statement).Range("N2:N70")     
                For Each Cell In rowstocheck
                If Cell.Value = "HIDE" Then
                        Cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                ElseIf Cell.Value <> "HIDE" Then Cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                End If
                Next Cell                                              
        If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
            DoEvents
        End If

        EmpName = MCST.Sheets(Statement).Range("C5")
        MgrName = MCST.Sheets(Statement).Range("K5")

        MgrPath = "C:\Users\" & User & "\Desktop\Manual Comp Statements\" & MgrName & "\"
        If Dir(MgrPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
            MkDir MgrPath
        End If

        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=MgrPath & "2018 Mid-Year Comp Statement - " & EmpName & ".pdf", _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False
        Printed = Printed + 1
    End If
    LoopRow = LoopRow + 1
Loop

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Sheets("Control Sheet").Activate

MsgBox "Execution Complete;" & vbCrLf & _
        Round((Now() - StartTime) * 86400, 0) & " Second Run Time." & vbCrLf & _
        (LoopRow - 2) & " Considered" & vbCrLf & _
        Printed & " Statements Printed"

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Resume Next
End Sub

Sub Reactivate_Functions()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I just feel that it doesn't need to be nearly this complex, does this seem overly complex for what I'm trying to achieve? I'd rather have something simpler so I can understand what to fix incase the code breaks.

Comment: First thing I see is that you loop through rows to hide rows. This can be improved on by using a filter and foregoing the loop

Comment: None of the optimizations are put into effect. They are true throughout.

Answer (score 0):

I started this but won't have time to finish today. I tried to condense this so you could follow and hopefully see the pain points yourself.

I would get rid of the `For Each MyCell` loop and just filter on your criteria `HIDE`. Looping & Hiding can be time consuming so a filter would be much faster.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Statement_Autoprint()

Dim StartTime As Date: StartTime = Now()

Dim MCST As Workbook: Set MCST = ActiveWorkbook
Dim User As String: User = Environ$("Username")
Dim SavePath As String: SavePath = "C:\Users\" & User & "\Desktop\Manual Comp Statements\"
Dim CS As Worksheet: Set CS = MCST.Sheets("Control Sheet")

Dim MgrPath As String, MyCell As Range, Printed As Integer, i As Integer, SM As Worksheet
Printed = 0

If Dir(SavePath, vbDirectory) <> "" Then
    MkDir SavePath
End If

Call Disable

For i = 2 To CS.Range("B" & CS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If CS.Range("A" & i) <> "" & CS.Range("B" & i) <> "" Then
        Set SM = MCST.Sheets(CS.Range("A" & i))
        SM.Calculate
        SM.Range("P1") = Format(CS.Range("B" & i), "000000000")

            For Each MyCell In SM.Range("N2:N70")
                If MyCell = "HIDE" Then
                    MyCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                ElseIf MyCell <> "HIDE" Then
                    MyCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                End If
            Next MyCell

        If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
            DoEvents
        End If

        MgrPath = "C:\Users\" & User & "\Desktop\Manual Comp Statements\" & SM.Range("K5") & "\"

        If Dir(MgrPath, vbDirectory) <> "" Then
            MkDir MgrPath
        End If

        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=MgrPath & "2018 Mid-Year Comp Statement - " & SM.Range("C5") & ".pdf", _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False

        Printed = Printed + 1
    End If
Next i

CS.Activate

Call Re_Enable

MsgBox "Execution Complete;" & vbCrLf & _
        Round((Now() - StartTime) * 86400, 0) & " Second Run Time." & vbCrLf & _
        (i - 2) & " Considered" & vbCrLf & _
        Printed & " Statements Printed"

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Disable()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Re_Enable()
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: the consolidation of this makes SO much more sense than what was previously there. What else were you intending on editing? Thanks a lot, so far, this looks amazing

Comment: Did you test it? Does it work the same way it did? It should be faster already. Let me know IF and HOW it runs now. Don't want to make any edits if I broke something

Comment: I'm going to be in the office in a couple of hours, I'll let you know when I get in.

Comment: I keep getting a pathway error here: `If Dir(SavePath, vbDirectory) <> "" Then
    MkDir SavePath
End If`

Comment: `Set SM = MCST.Sheets(CS.Range("A" & i))` type mismatch error here, too

Comment: You can try `CS.Range("A" & i).Value`

Comment: I'm going to delete the answer and may to to re-work if if i have time later. THis is the approach I would take though. The most important part is noticing the bottom two subs. The code you shared never turned all those options off which were there in the first place to boost run time

Comment: I get a "Run-time error 1004: document not saved. the document may be open, or an error may have been encountered when saving." when I try executing this block of code:

                        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                Filename:=MgrPath & "2018 Mid-Year Comp Statement - " & SM.Range("C5").Value & ".pdf", _
                                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                                OpenAfterPublish:=False